# Probability of tossing exactly 2 heads in 100 coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, permutations

I was able to figure it out when I was asked with 4 coin flips since there are 2^4 permutations out of which 6/16 had exactly 2 heads. However I do not know how to do this when the question now asks for 100 flips since there are now 2^100 possibilities and cannot just list them out.

It also says use counting principles but I haven't even made it that far since I do not know how to approach this question.

Comment: Read about binomial coefficients: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: I'm not sure what "counting principles" mean but I presume it means given 100 flips to make 2 heads there are ${100 \choose 2}$ ways for this to happen.  A harder way to do this is that there are $n=99$ flips where the first head could occur and $100-n$ remaining flips where the second may occur.  So there are $\sum_{i=1}^{99} (100 - i)$ ways to do it.  But an easier way that there are $n=99$ flips where the *second* flip can occur and $n-1$ *earlier* flips where the first could occur.  So $\sum_{n=2}^{100}(n-1)$.  Can you manipulate to show these are all the same?

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of the solution is to think of all the possible sequences of heads and tails that will satisfy the condition.  For instance, there are $2^{100}$ total sequences of coin flips when we flip a coin $100$ times (on each try we get two possible choices, but since there are $100$ in sequence we multiply all of these individual choices together).

To think about the particular sequences that satisfy the condition, consider all of the possible sequences that contain exactly two heads.  We can think of this equivalently as the problem of all the different ways of placing two balls in a tray with $100$ different possible slots.  Since there are ${100 \choose 2}$ to do this, our solution is

$$
\frac{\# \; of \; possible \; sequences}{total \; \# \; of \; sequences} \;\; =\;\; \frac{{100 \choose 2} }{2^{100}}.
$$

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but why is it 100P2?

Comment: @miweomnwirng Because you have $100$ different possible positions in the sequence (your heads could occur 32nd, and 95th in one sequence, or they may be 12th, 87th in another sequence) you need to figure out all of the possible positions in which your two heads occur in a sequence of $100$ flips.  The binomial factor here is the number which captures the number of ways of placing these values.

Comment: @miweomnwirng The usual explanation given for this is that say in placing your first coin you have $100$ options of slots.  For the second coin you only have $99$ options for slots, hence there are $100\cdot 99 = \frac{100!}{98!}$ ways of placing this.  Notice however, the above only works if we suppose our coins are distinguishable.  If they are indistinguishable we have to divide by $2!$, hence the total number is $\frac{100!}{98! \cdot 2!} = {100 \choose 2}$.

Comment: What if It asked for at least 2 heads, would I be able to use the difference of 100C1?

Comment: @miweomnwirng I'm not sure what $100C1$ means here, but you can think of it a couple of different ways.  If you want the probability of getting at least 2 heads then you'd have to do the same exact formulation above for each $k \in \{2,3,4,\ldots, 100\}$.  Alternatively you can consider the total number of sequences $2^{100}$ and simply subtract off the cases that don't match (getting exactly zero heads, or getting exactly 1 head).

Comment: $100C1$ is an alternate notation for ${100 \choose 1}$

Answer (score 0):

We need to choose $2$ of the $100$ flips to be heads with $p={1\over{2}}$ giving

$${100\choose{2}} {1\over{2}}^2 {1\over{2}}^{98} =3.904861\cdot10^{-27}$$

so this is almost impossible.

I would suggesting reading up on the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). One of the most important probability distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to list them out to know how many ways there are to get exactly $2$ heads.

Of the $100$ flips there are $100$ choices that may be a head.  Given that there are $99$ choices that can also be a head.  It doesn't matter which one you choice first so there are $\frac {100*99}2 =  {100 \choose 2}$ ways to flip exactly $2$ heads.  (Out of $100$ you have $2$ *choices*.  That's why they call $n \choose k$, $n$ *choose* $k$.)

So the probability is $\frac {\frac {100*99}2}{2^{100}} = \frac {50*99}{2^{100}} = \frac {25*99}{2^{99}}$  which is *really* small.